# Sub-sites can't access to style library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have got a site and multiple sub-sites under it. The problem I'm having is that all the JS files are located in Style Library of the master site, and users who don't have access to master site getting access denied errors.

I'm guessing this might be related to sub-sites don't have direct access to the Style Library of the master, but I'm not sure. (I'm not even sure whether this makes sense or not, I'm a newbie.)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users don't have access to the style library in the parent or root site, you're going to need to give them access.  You can probably just set the library with unique permissions and give everyone read access.  We have several site collections set up that way, where resources are stored in a single style library and given open access to allow users in subsites access.

Comment: Thanks for help Robbert, this fixed my problem. One question though; now when a user goes to a sub-site that doesn't have access to master site is getting a Security Warning: "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?" This is not the case for users who have access to the master site. Do you think this might have something to do with giving permissions just for the Style Library?

Comment: Sounds like you're delivering the site over https and referencing some content using http or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB in SharePoint 2013, the Master Page and Page Layouts library, as well as the top level site's Style Library have unique permissions enabled with a security group called Style Resource Readers that grants everyone in the site collection access to the library with read rights. Take a look at the Style Resource Readers permission level and/or group in your Style Library and make sure "everyone" is included in that group with Read or Restricted Read.

That being said, I prefer to put my JavaScript files in a folder called js in the same library as my Master Pages and Page Layouts (/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx) instead of the Style Library (/Style%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx).

For me, I'd rather keep these files "hidden" from my users as much as possible. While they can still access it from a direct link, it isn't out there like the Style Library is which users can get to from the Site Contents page. The Master Page and Page Layouts gallery link is hidden for non admin in Site Settings. It also makes linking to those files from my master page and page layouts much easier.

I do this for my site collection wide CSS, Images, and other assets.

Hope this helps!